# What is the difference in nuance and usage of the two kanji forms for なおす (naosu), 直す and 治す?

Tags: kanji, verbs

Stolen *directly* from Grigory M's question in the definition phase:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526?phase=definition

Comment: +1 for stealing someone else's question and using it as your own.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They both mean "to fix"/"to repair"/"to correct", but [治す](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E6%B2%BB%E3%81%99&stype=0&dtype=3) is used in the sense of "to heal or cure" ("to fix a disease"). "[直す](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E7%9B%B4%E3%81%99&stype=0&dtype=3)" is used for fixing, not healing.

EDIT: As per Tsuyoshi Ito's correction (confirmed with a bit of googling), I've removed a misleading bit about the object of these verbs.

Comment: So you mean 車を直す but 風邪を治す?

Comment: After stating that... I might have to qualify it.

Comment: The second paragraph does not make sense to me.  You can also say 故障を直す (fix a failure (of a machine etc.)) as well as 機械を直す (fix a machine), which are parallel to 病気を治す (heal a disease) and 病人を治す (heal an ill person).

Answer (score 5):

治す is only used **to heal** or **to cure**.

直す has more meanings, it can mean:

1)  to fix; to correct; to repair;

2) to replace; to put back as it was;

3)  to convert (into a different state); to transform;

Examples:

その本をなおしなさい。= Put back the book where you found it.

次の文章を日本語に直しなさい。= Put the following sentences into Japanese.

==

Source: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUE%E6%B2%BB%E3%81%99

Comment: +1 for "put back as it was/put away". This is used this way all the time, at least in Kyushu.

Comment: The use of なおす meaning to restore something to where it was (as in その本をなおしなさい) is observed in western Japan.  In 標準語, しまう is used for that meaning.